# Flex-box elements are stretching even with flex-start or spece around

Tags: css, flexbox

In this code, the 6 .choices divs always grow verticaly no matter what I do. I tried justify-content: flex-star, flex-end, space-between and space-around. I also tried differnet height for the .container.
In every cases, they always stretch to fill up the .container verticaly.

What can I do to prevent this?

```css
.container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    background-color: #0a0401;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
}

.choices{
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(30, 82, 60);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: share the html code also

Comment: If you just have a container div with 6 times choices div inside, these will stack vertically (because of `flex-direction: column;` , and only be 30px in height, since this is specified. 

Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Oh ok... I managed to make things work by applying a max-height to the .choices divs. Is that normal? All the solutions I have found online never mentioned this. Everyone  just say that applying flex-start should keep the elements from stretching.... weird..